# Azure Active Directory User Object Id (Guid) uniqueness across all AAD domains

Tags: azure-active-directory

I was not able to find any info on this. Can a user from any AAD domain have the same Object Id as a user from any other domain.  Or are these unique across all domains in Azure?

EDIT:  Is there a validation process in Azure that checks if a GUID has already been used for the same type of object, such as a RID Master in Windows AD..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all of the users in Azure has an unique object id no matter where the user comes from because the object id is GUID format, GUID is Globally Unique Identifier, it will generate an unique GUID for each user when add a user to Azure AD.

By the way, there could be two same object id(guid), but it's a very small probability(very very small, for example if you have 100,000,000 users in all of your AAD domains, the probability of exist two same object id is about 1/3.4×10^30, so we can ignore that).

Comment: Actually, GUID uniqueness is not a guarantee, its only a high probability.  The only way to guarantee uniqueness is to perform a validation.  In the ole Active Directory, there is a role call RID master.  This role ensures that all objects in the Forest have unique ID's.  SO my question really is., is there such a mechanism in Azure AD that ensures that every object of the same type has a unique ID..

Comment: @LastTribunal The GUID is generated based on machine information, current time and other factors. Are you sure you can generate two same GUIDs in real life...

Comment: Its not what I can generate, its what is, although highly unlikely, possible.  In a multitenant environment, it is possible that two user accounts from two AAD instances are created at the same time on the same machine and these two AAD instances became Tenants on my AAD integrated app.  The chances are extremely low, but still possible

Comment: @LastTribunal Yes it is possible to create two same object id, I think I have already mentioned it in the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: You should think about using the tenant id and object id to identify the user. Object id should be unique, but the tenant id will be useful to find the user in the multitenant scenario.