# Is it okay to rely on idp guid when linking accounts in a multi-tenant configuration?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've successfully implemented the following sample/custom policy in our B2C configuration:

[A B2C IEF Custom Policy which links a Federated login against a pre-created Local Account](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/link-local-account-with-federated-account)

Users from an Azure AD are allowed to login to our application if a Local Account exists. This Local Account includes a custom field that points to the `oid` of the AD user that wishes to login.

However, the sample is for single-tenant. I'm in the process of adjusting it for multi-tenant.

When linking an Azure AD user, is it okay to depend on the uniqueness of the `guid/oid`? Is the fact that a `guid` could be generated twice (even though it's really unlikely) a security risk? I.e. a second user with the same `guid` could have access to data they're not supposed to see?

I'm assuming it's not an issue within a single tenant - each user inside a single Directory needs to be unique. But is that true across all Azure AD Directories? Could one machine generate the same guid for two users across two different Directories?

Am I better off figuring out how to compare against the `issuer` and the `issuerUserId` in combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   `The ‘issuer’ and ‘issuerUserId’ input claims values represent the ‘socialaccountprovider’ or the ‘identityprovider’ and the ‘value’ of the key claim in base64 encoded format respectively`. Thus, the issuer value represents the **social identity provider** which provides the **identity details for logging in to the Azure AD B2C application** while the **issueruserID represents the secret value that is used by the IDP or that social identity provider for providing the identity details in an acceptable encrypted format to Azure AD B2C**.

•   And AFAIK, `GUID for an Azure AD user is unique as it itself abbreviates for Globally Unique Identifier`. Also, in Azure, **every user has a unique object ID no matter where the user comes from because the object ID is GUID format, and it will generate a unique GUID for each user when adding a user to Azure AD**.

But there could be **two same object id(guid)**, but it's a very **small probability (very very small, for example if you have 100,000,000 users in all your AAD domains, then the probability of existence of two same object id is about 1/3.4×10^30, so you can ignore that)**. You need to perform a **validation to guarantee the uniqueness of object ID and GUID in a domain**, so in AAD, the `GUID is generated based on machine information, current time, and other factors`.

Thus, when `you are talking about generating the same GUID for two users across different directories, you should think that for identifying a user, the object ID as well as tenant ID is used. In this case, if the object ID is unique then the tenant ID is useful to find the user in a multitenant scenario`. For more information, kindly refer to the below links: -

[Azure Active Directory User Object Id (Guid) uniqueness across all AAD domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61671021/azure-active-directory-user-object-id-guid-uniqueness-across-all-aad-domains)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/social-transformations

Comment: What I'm wondering is, what does Microsoft do when there's a guid collision (across all Azure ADs)? Do they check to see if a guid exists and generate a new one?

Comment: Yes, obviously as all the Azure AD directories are mapped and serviced by Azure Service Fabric which contains global mappings of all the virtual identities and resources deployed across all the Azure tenants which further prevents such from happening as they mapped to their tenant and subscription level in the background based on which even if query for a GUID or an object ID, our logging into the specified tenant or subscription becomes our reach or boundary.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify - you said, "our logging into the specified tenant or subscription becomes our reach or boundary". Do you mean that I should only rely on the combination of the users object id and tenent id? Never the user object id alone?

Comment: No, you can rely on the object ID alone to distinguish between same user logging into different tenants with the same credentials as the object ID for each of them will be different as OID claim or object ID property is immutable as well as Unique, so it should never change as well as it uniquely identifies the relevant directory object. I meant to say that the probability of users getting the same object ID is very very meek and remotely not possible as the OID is created based on time stamp, user info, etc.